# Gmail not receiving certain messages, are showing up in sent folder

Tags: c#, email, gmail, mandrill

I am trying to send an email notification to myself when the system has finished processing a payment. I am using the following code:

```
public Exception SendEmail(string subject, string body)
    try
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(Setting.Get("smtp_from"), Setting.Get("smtp_from_name"));
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(Setting.Get("smtp_to"), Setting.Get("smtp_to"));

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Setting.Get("smtp_host"),
            Port = Int32.Parse(Setting.Get("smtp_port")),
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, Setting.Get("smtp_password")),
            Timeout = Int32.Parse(Setting.Get("smtp_timeout"))
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }

        return null; //All went well
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

Nothing special about it, just basic code found with Google. This code works flawlessly with the following message and subject:

```
Subject: [SUCCESS] Donation processed successfully
Message: This is a test.
```

But, when the message changes to this:

```
Donation received and processed successfully! No further action is required.
Donor: John Doe
Donation amount: 4,00 EUR
Email: fake@user.com
Mandrill API Response: Sent
```

Nothing shows up in my inbox. It does show up in the sent items of the account sending the email. I have checked everything, spam, thrash, but it just doesn't arrive.

Has anyone encountered this before? Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

Look at this:

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
})
{
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

The using statement is disposing the MailMessage before the .Send(message) method is called, and for some reason this does not produce an exception. *facepalms*

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
 public static void SendEmail(string emailbody)
    {
      MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("incoming email address", "receiver email address");
      mailMessage.Body = emailbody;
      mailMessage.Subject = "Feedback";

      SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
      smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
      smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The contents can be added separately into the emailbody. For example `string Contents = "Donation received and processed successfully! No further action is required.
Donor: John Doe
Donation amount: 4,00 EUR
Email: fake@user.com
Mandrill API Response: Sent";` And then:   `SendEmail(Contents);`

Comment: The function is called with those as parameters.